# opening a .txt file in same folder as .py not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My vscode is having problems using the open() function to open a file.

I am trying to open a .txt file. Both the py file and .txt file are in the same folder (named "practice"), but python terminal is erroring out with

```
File "c:\Users\liamt\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCode\Practice\p2.py", line 4, in <module>
    fin = open('ex_text.txt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ex_text.txt'
PS C:\Users\liamt\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCode> python -
```

I tried using the relative path to the .txt file but a permission error came up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\liamt\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCode\Practice\p2.py", line 4, in <module>
    fin = open('C:\\Users\\liamt\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VSCode\\Practice')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\liamt\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VSCode\\Practice'    
PS C:\Users\liamt\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCode>
```

What am I doing wrong? Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please include the code in text, not image ([Why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)).

Comment: The 2nd image might be because of [Microsoft's controlled folder access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/controlled-folders?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: what does cd mean?

Answer (score 2):

When using vscode, open the entire folder/directory containing all the files by using file > open folder, and not just double clicking the python file alone. By opening the entire folder, it is included in the workspace and can be opened by the python file that exists along with it.

Comment: thank you so much! now i can get back to studying !

Comment: OMG, superb answer worked like charm.